# How to access value in params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

These are my params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"xiWiAmt4BUsPZc/Yq2DJCrVdNsxkBCk6njhmOtr2dz0=",
 "price"=>{"{:value=>7900}"=>""}
```

I'm trying to assign the value (i.e. 7900) to an object in my controller:
`@amount = params[:price][:value]`

Does not seem to work.

Comment: How did you end up with this params? Your problem is not how to access value, your problem is why your hash has been converted to string and used a s key.

Comment: `<%= hidden_field :price, :value => rate.price.to_i * 100 %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you assigning the hash to price?

Your issue is that price contains a hash which has a key of `"{:value=>7900}"` with a value of `""`. This means that `params[:price][:value]` won't bring back anything and `params[:price]['{:value=>7900']` would work but return you the value of `""`.

Take a look at how you are setting that value of price and make sure that it is being set correctly.

OK, with your comment it is more clear what is happening.

Because you are just using <%= hidden_field :price %> it is setting the name to the value that you have given it which in this case is price[value7900]. This is because hidden_field is taking three parameters, `hidden_field(:object, :field, :value => params[:requestval])`. So you are passing value7900 into the field parameter. The fix is just to add that missing parameter.

```
<%= hidden_field :price, :value, :value => rate.price.to_i * 100 %>
```

I know the value tag looks redundant but that is because one is setting the name of the parameter and the other is actually setting the value.

This is the HTML that it produces.

```
<input id="price_value" name="price[value]" type="hidden" value="7900">
```

The reason you need to use all three variables here and not in other places is becuase you aren't using a form object. Had this been wrapped around with a form and using the object you wouldn't need the first parameter.

```
<%= form_for @price do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :value, :value => rate.price.to_i * 100 %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `<%= hidden_field :price, :value => rate.price.to_i * 100 %>`

Answer (score 2):

Your `hidden_field` is incorrect. It should be:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :price, rate.price.to_i * 100 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just parse it:

```
@amount = params[:price].keys.first[/\d+/].to_i
```